# Angular 4+ Granular control over http call to show / hide loader

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I have a service making http call and getting data back as Observable and i am assigning it to a variable in the component like follows

```
this.usersResponse$ = this.dataSvc.getUsers(pageNumber);
```

On html i am doing the follows

```html
<div *ngIf="usersResponse$ | async as userResponse; else loading">
    <ng-container>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let user of userResponse.data" (click)="detail(user.id)">
                <img [src]="user.avatar" alt="">
                <p>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ng-container>    
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
    <app-loading></app-loading>
</ng-template>
```

What i want to achieve is how to get a granular control to show loader before http call then make http call get the data back and turn off the loader, so that the UI is jumpy.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use complete event:

```
 this.showLoader=true;
this.usersResponse$ = this.dataSvc.getUsers(pageNumber);
this.usersResponse$.subscribe(null, null, () => 
this.showLoader=false);
```

In template

```
   <app-loading *ngIf="showLoader"></app-loading>
```

Comment: as we are subscribing to the userResponse$ observable, do we have to manually unsubscribe on component destroy?

Comment: His answer implicates that the showLoader will be set to false when the observer completes. When the observer completes the subscriptions will no longer be active, so no need to manually unsubscribe, if those conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it reactive way with the help of simple monad:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-loadable-content

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import {LoadableContent} from 'ng-loadable-content';

@Injectable()
export class ObjectStore {

    private readonly _state = new BehaviorSubject<LoadableContent<UserResponse>>(LoadableContent.initial());
    readonly state$ = this._state.asObservable();

    constructor(private readonly dataSvc: RemoteService) {
    }

    reload(pageNumber: number) {
        this._state.next(LoadableContent.loading());
        this.dataSvc.getUsers(pageNumber)
            .subscribe(
                res => this._state.next(LoadableContent.loaded(res)),
                e => this._state.next(LoadableContent.error(e))
            );
    }

}
```

controller:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {LoadableContent} from 'ng-loadable-content';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-object',
    templateUrl: './object.component.html',
    providers: [ObjectStore]

})
export class ObjectComponent {

    readonly state$: Observable<LoadableContent<UserResponse>>;

    constructor(private readonly objectStore: ObjectStore) {
        this.state$ = objectStore.state$;
        this.objectStore.reload(1);
    }

}
```

template:

```
<div>
    
    <ng-container *ngIf="state$ | async as state">
        <div *ngIf="state | loaded as dto">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let user of dto.data" (click)="detail(user.id)">
                <img [src]="user.avatar" alt="">
                <p>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <app-loading *ngIf="state | loading"></app-loading>
        <div *ngIf="state | loadError">
            Failed to load
        </div>
    </ng-container>

</div>
```